# sfml картинка отстает от кода

Tags: sfml

```
void Visualisation::startGame() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1920, 1080), "BlackJack");

    setBackground("blackjack.jpg");
    setDealerCardsImage("cardsDealer.png");
    setPlayerCardsImage("cardsPlayer.png");
    setAvatarsImage("avatars.png");
    setFont("Orbitron-Black.ttf");
    sf::Event event;


    ofstream time;
    time.open("time.txt");

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Clock clock;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        vector<string> names;
        names.push_back("pl1");
        names.push_back("pl2");
        names.push_back("pl3");
        names.push_back("Komputer");
        names.push_back("Lexa");

        setPlayers(names);

        Game game(names, 5, this);


            setPlayers(names);
            game.play();


            window.clear();
            window.draw(background.sprite);
            for (auto dealerCard : dealerCards) {
                window.draw(dealerCard);
            }

            for (auto player : players) {
                window.draw(player.second->sprite);
                window.draw(player.second->text);
            }
            for (auto cards : playersCards) {
                for (auto card : cards.second) {
                    window.draw(card);
                }
            }

            window.draw(dealerPoints);
            window.display();
            clearPlayersCards();
            dealerCards.clear();

            time << "all circle: " <<clock.restart().asMilliseconds() << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

функция, отвечающая за отрисовку
[видос происходящего](https://youtu.be/VrHtbKAhYyU)

прошу заметить как быстро идет рассчет и как медленно идет отрисовка, на глаз примерно один кадр в секунду, в свою очередь каждое прохождение цикла занимает около 5 милисекунд[image: введите сюда описание изображения], отчего картинка отстает от кода и при паузе исполнения анимация продолжает идти, и данный фпс не меняется ни при уменьшении объектов, ни при window.setFramerateLimit(n);, в чем же проблема?

Comment: в то же время, если добавить куб и двигать его, он будет двигаться нормально, ничего не понимаю

Comment: словил в дебаге dealerCards из одного цикла и из следующего, если успеть нажать следующий шаг быстрее чем за секунду, то значение не изменится

Comment: вроде программа не успевает считать, но она ведь успевает, к тому же независимо от количества спрайтов время всегда остается этой секундой